# HG Mercurial Check Out Question

Tags: urdf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm new to this ROS business and I needed help with TF and URDF.  Usually I "svn co" something, but these two packages require me to "hg" the link.  I have

"sudo apt-get install mercurial"

the mercurial SCM, but when i try to hg these packages it says

"abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!"

I don't know where to go from here.  Thanks in advance for the help!

-Matthew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10062/hg-mercurial-check-out-question/) by [a11irap](https://answers.ros.org/users/596/a11irap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mercurial is pretty straightforward, as an example:

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_ros
```

You can always grab the latest version with:

```
hg pull
hg update
```

And you can see other branches with the "branches" command:

```
hg branches
```

For anything more than that, I would suggest the [Mercurial Quickstart](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/QuickStart)

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-05-27**:
Joel Spolsky's tutorial (http://hginit.com/) is excellent, as well.